# Why can I not access querySelectors out of scope?

Tags: javascript, css, react-hooks

I'm working on a HTML/CSS/React/JS project, and want to refactor the duplicate lines I have assigning variables to different class-elements. In this example, I have an event-listener that changes the scale of a div based on the window size.

```
import React from 'react';

function Home() {
  const [scrollX, setScrollX] = React.useState(document.body.scrollWidth);
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState(document.body.scrollHeight);

  const resizeCallback = () => {
    const rotateName = document.querySelector('.rotateName');
    const y = document.body.scrollHeight / scrollY;
    const x = document.body.scrollWidth / scrollX;

    rotateName.style.scale = x * y * 1.2;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCallback);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeCallback);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="rotateName">
        <p>My name is</p>
        <div className="firstN"><h1>John</h1></div>
        <div className="lastN"><h1>Doe</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

When I place rotateName on Line 8 (inside resizeCallback) to the outer-most scope in the Home function like Line 6, it stops working. My understanding of scopes and closures is that variables declared outside of a block can be used in inner functions?

Does this problem have to do with the processes of React.useEffect(), or is it a conceptual misunderstanding of closures on my part?

Comment: If you put it before that, the `.rotateName` element hasn't been added to the DOM yet, so `document.querySelector(".rotateName")` doesn't return anything. You're returning the element from the function, so it doesn't exist during when you first call it. But it will exist later when the event occurs.

Comment: What made you think this was a scope problem? Did you get an error message saying that the variable doesn't exist? I'd expect it to just say that `rotateName` is `null`.

Comment: The linter would say rotateName is undefined if placed somewhere else. If it's a DOM related problem, is there a common technique I can use to declare it within the entire component? Something like prop-types, or assigning it via a useState()?

Comment: The linter shouldn't have any problem with this. It knows about scope rules.

Comment: As I said above, this has nothing to do with scope. It's about timing.

Comment: You can't get the element with `document.querySelector()` until you add the element to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! I found a quick post highlighting this exact problem with timing. I'm looking into storing the selectors as references and then updating the values during event handlers.

https://flaviocopes.com/dom-timing/